# Using Limit and offset in Sqlite update statmet

Tags: sqlite

```
update table set column_name limit 3 offset 2;
```

The above query is not working.

Throws error

sql error: syntax error near ***'limit'***.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An UPDATE statement expects a new value after the `column_name`, like this:

```sql
update thetable set column_name = 'some new value'
```

Furthermore, the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_update.html) mentions that you need to have compiled SQLite with the [SQLITE_ENABLE_UPDATE_DELETE_LIMIT](http://www.sqlite.org/compile.html#enable_update_delete_limit) option, which is *not* enabled by default.

Answer (score 0):

Sqlite does not allow the use of LIMIT and OFFSET statements like in MYSQL. You will have to use a nested query to workaround it . Or use two queries.